# Content Security Policy enables inline styling for one source

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

I am using a third-party external source file:

```
  var s1 = document.createElement("script"), s0 = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  s1.async = true;
  s1.src = 'https://some_external_source.com';
  s1.charset = 'UTF-8';
  s1.setAttribute('crossorigin', '*');
  s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1, s0);
```

The external source codes `'https://some_external_source.com'` contain some inline-styling. The content security policies of my web app does not allow any inline-styling, and I am unable to change the codes of the external source. Therefore, is it possible to allow inline-styling only for the `'https://some_external_source.com'`, and block for other sources? If so, how should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

CSP have no possibility to allow styles individually on per-script base. But it's possible to allow individually each inline-style using it hash.

There are 2 kind of inline styles:

1. The `<style>...</style>`block - could be allowed with `sha256-value_of_block`;
2. The *style=* attribyte in tag `<tag style='...some styles here...'>` - could be allowed with `sha256-value_of_style=` + 'unsafe-hashes' token (it's support by browsers could be checked [here](https://csplite.com/csp/test296/)).

Negative moments are you have to add a lot of hashes if dozens of `<tag styles='...'` the kind of (2.) and recalc hashes when those are changed. But in case of inline styles the kind of (1.) - it is an ordinary practice to use such hashes.

PS: 'sha256' is only as an example, you can use 'sha384' or 'sha512' hashes too.

PPS: Inline styles the kind of (2.) includes script `HTMLElement.setAttribute()` calls. It will be real headake to make hashes for all of them.

Comment: Hi @granty, thanks for your response. The inline styling is from an external file that I do not have access to. Can I enable the inline styling for that whole file with the methods you described here?

Comment: If under "whole file" you mean javascript-file, the answer is no. Hashes could be used to allow specific inline-style, ex. `style='background-color:green; padding:5px;position:absolute;'`. If you specify hash of the string `background-color:green; padding:5px;position:absolute;` in the CSP header, this style will be allowed to apply ('unsafe-hashes' token required too). With the `<style>...</style>` situation is the same, but you do not need 'unsafe-hashes' token be specified.